# Loop through data to pull array of firebase values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a an array of a number of N paths to retrieve data from a different location in firebase database.

`searchPaths = ['locations/date1/imageID', 'locations/date2/imageID2', locations/date3/imageID3, ...]`

now, I want to loop through each search path and pull a value from it to save an array of image URL's.

```
    const searchPaths = ['locations/date1/imageID', 'locations/date2/imageID2']
    const imageURLs = []

     for(var Obj in searchPaths) 
    {
        const path = Obj
        admin.database().ref(path).once('value').then(snapshot => 
        { 
        const URL = snapshot.val().fileURL;
        imageURLs.push(URL);
        console.log('ImageURL: ' + URL );
        })
    // here is where it gets sour
    }.then(() => {
        console.log("All image URL's" + imageURLs")
    }
```

So, my question is, how do I return a promise when we have now pulled the data we need from every ref? is there a `Promise.all` type? where does it go?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for-loop to create an array of promises, then use `Promise.all`, crude I know but it should work.

```
const searchPaths = ['locations/date1/imageID', 'locations/date2/imageID2']
const imageURLs = []
var promises = [];
 for(var Obj in searchPaths) 
{
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const path = Obj
      admin.database().ref(path).once('value').then(snapshot => 
      { 
      const URL = snapshot.val().fileURL;
      imageURLs.push(URL);
      console.log('ImageURL: ' + URL );

      //resolve the promise after pushing imageURL
      resolve();
      })
    }));
}

//when all of them are done:
Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(results) {
  //code when done...
})
```

Comment: A `Promise` object has three states: pending, resolved, and reject. Any `Promise` object is built with a function with two parameters: the resolve and reject functions. When the `resolve` is called, the promise will `resolve`, and return a value, and similarly with `reject`, but in `reject`'s case an error will be thrown. In this code, we are essentially leaving the promise in the "pending" state until we call `resolve` to resolve the promise when the images are loaded. We then fill an array with these promises, then use them in Promise.all, which waits for all promises to resolve.

Comment: There's too much work going on here.  once() returns a promise, so there's no need to create a new promise object each time.  Please see my answer here for a shorter and more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here is going through too much trouble to collect promises.  It's easier to just push the return value of once() into the promises array rather than creating a new promise each time.

```
const searchPaths = ['locations/date1/imageID', 'locations/date2/imageID2']
const imageURLs = []
const promises = []   // collect promises here

searchPaths.forEach(path => {
    promises.push(admin.database().ref(path).once('value'))
})

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    results.forEach(snapshot => {
        const URL = snapshot.val().fileURL;
        imageURLs.push(URL);
        console.log('ImageURL: ' + URL );
    }
})
```

The `then` callback on the promise returned from Promise.all() will be an array of all the snapshots from the queries pushed into the `promises` array.